# Jetpack Compose dragging element to another column

Tags: drag-and-drop, android-jetpack-compose

My situation: I have 2 columns and I want to move boxes between them. A simple flow is not working (picture on the bottom).

1. I have boxes A, B and C in column 1
2. I drag box A into column 2, it appears there - up to this point everything is fine
3. I drag box C into column 2, BUT after I drop it, box B appears there. Before I drop it everything is fine, box C is actually moving on screen, only after I drop it box B appears there instead

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material3.Divider
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    val data = mapOf(
        1 to listOf("A", "B", "C"),
        2 to listOf()
    )

    Row {
        var state by remember { mutableStateOf(data) }

        state.forEach { (_, notes) ->
            NoteColumn(notes = notes) { note ->
                val newFirstColumn = state.get(1).orEmpty().minus(note)
                val newSecondColumn = state.get(2).orEmpty().plus(note)
                state = mapOf(
                    1 to newFirstColumn,
                    2 to newSecondColumn
                )
            }

            Divider(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().width(1.dp))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NoteColumn(notes: List<String>, move: (String) -> Unit) {
    Column {
        notes.forEach {
            Text(text = it, modifier = Modifier
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress(
                        onDragStart = {},
                        onDrag = { change, _ -> change.consume() },
                        onDragEnd = { move.invoke(it) },
                        onDragCancel = {}
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is the simplest code I could make to demonstrate this. What happens is, when I try to drag C box, `onDragEnd` is called on the B box, I can see it in debugger. I have no idea why that is, and how to fix it. I'm new to jetpack compose, I tried to change the state to `mutableMapOf` or other combinations, but nothing seemed to help, and I can't see how that would be the problem anyway.

Funny thing is that it works with `draggable`, only `pointerInput` seems to be the problem. Sadly for my real use-case I cannot use `draggable`.

//EDIT - Found [this](https://tabris.com/update-state-in-jetpack-compose/) and it seems to work. Still waiting for better solutions or confirmations this is indeed the only correct one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the new (`implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.01.00')`) **drag and drop** functionality, which can natively help you recognize the type of data that is being dragged (such as UID of an A item) and the specific source.

Here's a demo example of how you can work with drag and drop:

```
       Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(60.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .dragAndDropSource {
                    detectTapGestures(
                        onLongPress = {
                            startTransfer(
                                DragAndDropTransferData(
                                    ClipData(
                                        "",
                                        arrayOf("array of mimeTypes - those tell dragAndDropTargets which type of dragAndDropSource this is, such as an image, text, phone number, or your custom type"),
                                        ClipData.Item("you can add new clip items with data here")
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    )
                },
            color = Color.Black,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            text = "Hold me to drag and drop"
        )
        val enteredIndex = remember {
            mutableIntStateOf(-1)
        }

        LazyColumn {
            items(50) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .then(
                            if (enteredIndex.intValue == it) {
                                Modifier.background(Color.White)
                            } else Modifier.background(Color.Cyan)
                        )
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(80.dp)
                        .dragAndDropTarget(
                            shouldStartDragAndDrop = {
                                true
                            },
                            target = object : DragAndDropTarget {
                                override fun onDrop(event: DragAndDropEvent): Boolean {
                                    enteredIndex.intValue = -1
                                    return true
                                }
                                override fun onEntered(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                    super.onEntered(event)
                                    enteredIndex.intValue = it
                                }
                                override fun onExited(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                    super.onExited(event)
                                    enteredIndex.intValue = -1
                                }
                            }
                        ),
                    color = Color.Black,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    text = "Content $it, that responds to drag and drop"
                )
            }
        }
```

Personally, I find good use of the drag and drop, as you can show the user where he's putting the item, and you can also draw either custom dragAndDropSource to visualize what the user is holding or *Compose* does it for you. You can also expand colorful Boxes as spaces where user can put items.

After `onDrop` is called, you can just add the item into the other `Column`. In that case, I'd strongly recommend using `LazyColumn` with keys, where you can easily animate the appearance of the new item.

See more here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2024/01/whats-new-in-jetpack-compose-january-24-release.html